# Flutter with Segment Analytics

Tags: flutter, segment-io, segment-analytics

I am trying to add Segment-Analytics to a Flutter app but currently, after adding the lib my app seems to be unable to start, however the build was still successful. lib: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_segment

when i run flutter run:

```
Waiting for iPhone 12 Pro Max to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60371/UvkZwEEEE9Q=/ws
Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
Lost connection to device.
```

with verbose Ending few lines:

```
[   +2 ms] Updating assets
[ +800 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
[  +84 ms] Syncing files to device iPhone 12 Pro Max...
[   +3 ms] Scanning asset files
[  +40 ms] <- reset
[        ] Compiling dart to kernel with 0 updated files
[   +7 ms] <- recompile package:foobar/main.dart ca15a951-5490-4e2d-b153-7b8a5eeeb160
[        ] <- ca15a951-5490-4e2d-b153-7b8a5eeeb160
[   +9 ms] flutter: [debug] release: my.foobar.testseg@0.0.2+2
[   +5 ms] Service protocol connection closed.
[   +2 ms] Lost connection to device.
[ +294 ms] Updating files
[   +8 ms] Error writing "build/flutter_assets/assets/images/gadget.png" to DevFS: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 63860
[        ] trying again in a few - 9 more attempts left
[        ] Error writing "build/flutter_assets/assets/images/logo/ticked.svg" to DevFS: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 63861
[        ] trying again in a few - 9 more attempts left
[   +1 ms] Error writing "build/flutter_assets/assets/images/logo/kyc.svg" to DevFS: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 63862
[        ] trying again in a few - 9 more attempts left
```

any suggestions on how to work around for flutter to be able to send analytics data to segment analytics, from the web app it doesn't support it for the moment.

P/S: Any alternative SW suggestions would also be helpful thanks.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Yes manage to resolve it the same way as you suggested, at the manifest.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Segment write-key to the native configuration,
this would resolve it for now. there is an open issue -
https://github.com/claimsforce-gmbh/flutter-segment/issues/87

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  [...]
  <key>com.claimsforce.segment.WRITE_KEY</key>
  <string>YOUR_WRITE_KEY_GOES_HERE</string>
  <key>com.claimsforce.segment.TRACK_APPLICATION_LIFECYCLE_EVENTS</key>
  <false/>
  <key>com.claimsforce.segment.ENABLE_AMPLITUDE_INTEGRATION</key>
  <false/>
  [...]
</dict>
</plist>
```